# Why do I get an error when installing Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

1. I have the newest Java version which I downloaded from their page right before this post.
2. I have Java JDK 14.0.2.
3. I have paths made:

[image: paths]

[image: Eclipse Installation Folders]

Installation log:

```
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Executing bootstrap tasks
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_261-b12
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2020-06
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.17.0.v20200606-0914, build=4683, branch=11a8454bc4da69195dc3e9f065bbd8fe43f77e1e
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.17.0.v20200531-1047, build=4683, branch=11a8454bc4da69195dc3e9f065bbd8fe43f77e1e
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.15.0.v20200531-1047, build=4683, branch=11a8454bc4da69195dc3e9f065bbd8fe43f77e1e
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2020-06))
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Offline = false
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Mirrors = true
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Resolving 16 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\Users\emman\java-2020-065\eclipse
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.java [4.16.0,5.0.0)
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.16.0,5.0.0)
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.16.0,5.0.0)
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-06
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06/202006171000
    [2020-07-15 11:58:49] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
    [2020-07-15 11:58:51] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
    [2020-07-15 11:58:51] Computing prerequisite plan
    [2020-07-15 11:58:53] Collecting 3 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06/202006171000
    [2020-07-15 11:58:54] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
    [2020-07-15 11:58:54] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
    [2020-07-15 11:58:54] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
    [2020-07-15 11:58:54] Collected 3 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06/202006171000 in 0.348s
    [2020-07-15 11:58:54] Collecting 1 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-06
    [2020-07-15 11:58:54] Downloading epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
    [2020-07-15 11:58:54] Collected 1 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-06 in 0.005s
    [2020-07-15 11:58:56] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
    [2020-07-15 11:58:56] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
      at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:550)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:342)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:882)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3827)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3755)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3736)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3629)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1342)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1204)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1149)
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_emman_java-2020-065_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
      java.io.IOException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\emman\.p2\pool\features\org.eclipse.userstorage_1.2.0.v20191120-1614
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:546)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:882)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3827)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3755)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3736)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3629)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1342)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1204)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1149)
      Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\emman\.p2\pool\features\org.eclipse.userstorage_1.2.0.v20191120-1614 (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:322)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:546)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:882)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3827)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3755)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3736)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3629)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1342)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1204)
         1 more
    
    [2020-07-15 11:58:56]
```

Comment: Try again and if that fails again, reinstall the Eclipse Installer or [download the IDE package as ZIP directly](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you got a broken build. There are user that has been reported such behaviour.

Please take a look on this thread, maybe will solve your problem:

- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1780180/?srch=repair+bundle+pool#msg_1780180